# Parse xml with empty valued attribute

Tags: java, xml, performance, xml-parsing

Have and input of this format:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr bgcolor='#999999'>
        <td nowrap width='1%'>
        </td>
        <td nowrap width='3%' align='center'>
            <font style='font-size: 8pt'> System ID </font>
        </td>
        <td nowrap width='5%' align='center'>
```

In order to remove **nowrap** attribute , was earlier using this code:

```
    if (deletedString == null)
    {
        return exportedTable;
    }

    int tagPos = 0;
    String resultTable = exportedTable;
    while (resultTable.indexOf(deletedString) != -1)
    {
        tagPos = resultTable.indexOf(deletedString, tagPos);
        String beforTag = resultTable.substring(0, tagPos);
        String afterTag = resultTable.substring(tagPos + deletedString.length());

        resultTable = beforTag + afterTag;
    }
    return resultTable;
```

deletedString is nowrap, and input is exportedTable.
But this is causing Performance issues. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation: [StringUtils.remove(source, substring)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) will remove all instances of the substring from the source string.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18297346/1827903) benchmarked this method and found it to be five times faster than a few alternatives.

Alternatively, use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to aggregate your substrings - every time you concatenate two strings you're creating a new string, whereas `StringBuilder` is mutable and doesn't need to create a new copy on an update.

Comment: I will try with the first approach as u suggested. For the second one, actually the performance lag is more due to the no of iterations of while loop, than the String concatenation part.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a xmlstreamreader and have a while loop that parses through the xml as long as the streamreader.hasNext().

Format:

```
//Create stream reader
//Position at beginning of document

//While the stream reader has next (can see next line)
//perform action
```